# Is there some way I get 301 error while proxy_pass is returning 502 error?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

```
location / {
   proxy_pass /newurl/;
}

location /newurl {
   return 303 /old/users;
}
```

I am trying to access / and getting 502 error, as my proxy to /newurl is returning an error 301.
Is there some way I can proxy and get the 301 error with the same content to UI?

Comment: You need to explain the issue with a bit more detail. The cause appears to be that you are redirecting to a location that doesn't exist (`/newurl`). Thus the 301 (redirect) => 502 (bad gateway).

Comment: I need to send 301 redirect error back instead of 502.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using proxy_pass take a look at the rewrite directive.

You are receiving the 502 error message because the proxy_pass directive in your snippet is not pointing to a valid URL.

```
location / {
 rewrite ^ /newurl break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest share a complete nginx block so we can see what you doing wrong

```
server {
    . . .
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    rewrite ^/products.html$ /offer.html permanent;
    rewrite ^/services.html$ /offer.html permanent;
    . . .
}
```